# Z-scale before Correlations?

Tags: correlation

Is it valid  to z normalise data before doing Pearson's or spearman's correlation on curves? Currently I am z normalising my data and then running a spearman's correlation, from there I can generate p values.

What I'm looking is signals from a set of signals that have a statistically significant difference, and the above is the method I have used.

Comment: Did you try it to see how the standardization affects the correlations?

Answer (score 1):

Standardisation, i.e. subtraction of the mean and division by the standard deviation, is a linear transformation of your data. Neither Pearson's nor Spearman's correlation coefficient depend on the absolute values, hence neither will be affected by standardisation.

As ttnphns commented: try and see that there is no difference.